# CSS only apply margin to first line

Tags: css, background, move

I have an icon set that uses CSS classes to display them accordingly. Like, say, this:

```
<div class="icon anchor">This is some text!<br>This is some text!</div>
```

This will display the icon, but since the icon is a background image, the text has to be moved aside, to make room so that the text isn't going over the image. That's where my problem is. The text is moved aside, but *all* the text is moved aside. I only want what *needs(probably the first line)* to be moved. This is my CSS:

```
.icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 17px;
}
.icon.anchor{ 
    background-image: url(fugue-icons-3.0-src/icons/anchor.png); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this instead:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/8uPU5/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="icon anchor"><span>This is some text!</span><br>This is some text!</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.icon.anchor span {
    padding-left: 17px;
}
.icon.anchor{ 
    background-image: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/0b/Vovinam_azzurro_16x16.gif);
}
```

Comment: This is A right answer, but not completely what I was looking for. But it pointed me in the right direction. The idea was that you didnt need to know what the first line is. Just snap to the first line, container-wise.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to indent the first row of text, then the proper CSS-property is the [text-indent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#indentation-prop) property. It will set the left margin (or right margin in right-to-left languages) to the first line of any block container. In this case the CSS would be

```
.icon {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-indent: 17px;
}
.icon.anchor{ 
    background-image: url(fugue-icons-3.0-src/icons/anchor.png); 
}
```

[See it in action at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8uPU5/2/).

Answer (score 2):

What about the `:first-line` pseudo-selector? i.e.

```
div.icon.anchor:first-line { ... }
```

But why is that a `<div>` and not a `<p>` (or two)?